# Using Guice Injection with flatspecs "behave" feature for sharing tests

Tags: scala, testing, dependency-injection, guice

How can flatspecs [behave](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests) functionality be used in conjunction with guice and injecting an application ?

In our setup we see calls to code marked below before the application is available and therefor no injector is there as well.

Basic example

```
it should behave like someControllerFunction(p1, p2, p3) {
   //This is the block of code that gets executed before the injector and application is setup !
   val classUnderTest = app.injector.instanceOf[ClassUnderTest]
   classUnderTest.method()(_)
}
```

Comment: Thomas, how do you run your tests? And where do you set up your injector? In other words why do you expect that the injector will be set up at all when you run your tests?

Comment: @SergGr Updated the question to give you more information.

Comment: @Serendipity, sorry but currently the last update seems to be made on "Nov 17". Where did you added more information?

Comment: @SergGr apologies, my edit has mysteriously vanished :P. I was editing to show that this comes from a `OneAppPerTest` base class that is modified to provide the fakeApp via a GuiceApplicationBuilder. In the non-behavioral tests/specs, the app and it's corresponding injector are available within the scope of this pattern `it should "do something" in { //app is available }`

Comment: @Serendipity, ThomasS sorry, but you really should provide more context code so we can see what you do. It is really hard to guess by what I see now. What is `OneAppPerTest`? Is that the base class for all your specs? Or is it an independent class? If so, how `app` is visible inside the specs? How `fakeApp` is related to `app`? What is the signature of  `someControllerFunction` so that you pass additional parameter via block there? What is the intention of this trick? There are just more questions than answers.

Comment: I know this is a really late response. But `OneAppPerTest` is one of the base classes provided by ScalaTest. See this documentation in Play 2.4: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest

Comment: And the _trick_ is about sharing tests (or behavior) as shown here: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests